# Error when I try to install my application on my device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

Today I try do make this application : https://medium.com/@diprochowdhury/developing-a-movies-app-with-picasso-and-themoviedb-org-api-using-fragments-eb1bd19cf572

but at the end, I have this error when I try to install my application :
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS
Installation failed due to: 'null'
Retry

[image]

Someone understand it? I have made a lot of research on internet but I don't find anything about this.

Thanks

Comment: are u using an emulator ?

Comment: Same error on emulator and on my device